# Как скрыть div ы начиная с третьего

Tags: css3

Как скрыть div ы начиная с третьего т.е. есть 10 div и начиная с 3 нужно их скрыть?

Comment: Хорошая дока у мозиллы https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#compound-selector. Если вы работаете с css, то обязательно просмотрите её хотя бы по диагонали. Просто в конце рабочего/учебного дня по 10 минут читайте, что вообще есть в css, -- очень помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто css.

так:

```css
div {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:nth-child(1),
div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

или так:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

ну или так:

```css
div {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:nth-child(-n+2) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = i + 1;
  root.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#root > div:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Подробнее о `nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation)

Comment: -n+3 это первые три. Проставьте числа в дивы, чтобы видеть, что вы скрыли (по цветам сложно сориентироваться).

Comment: Я бы обернул эти `div`, т.к. в снипете первый элемент у `body` - `script`, который является `:nth-child(1)`, из-за этого пример ломается логически, ибо мы видим `1, 2`, при условии того, что должны быть видны `1,2,3`.. Чёт запутанно объяснил :D

Comment: @entithat, во, просто как-то логичнее, нежели изначально где `n+4`, а показывается всё равно первые два)